# Using rn:page_title in the Meta Description Tag with Oracle RightNow

Tags: php, rightnow-crm

I need to use this tag `<rn:page_title/>` in my `<meta name="description" content=""/>` tag on my template files. I need specifically for the content to read something like:
"Read more about `<rn:page_title/>` on our site!"

I realize that this tag is really just a shortcut for the `<rn:meta>` tag from the content that I'm sucking into my template.
How can I access the `<rn:page_title/>` content while inside an HTML tag?

- Is there a way to save the results of this tag in a php variable?
- I need to make sure it renders with the page, not after, so using JavaScript to build the meta tag and injecting it after page render is not an option.
- Is there a way to dynamically retrieve the results of the `<rn:meta>` tag? Perhaps with an `#rn:php:some/path/getDymanicTitle()#` statement in the content string? But I don't know how getDynamicTitle works, and I need it to work not just on answers pages, but on all pages.

Answer (score 0):

After searching for several days to figure out how to do this in the most flexible way possible I came up with this snarky little piece of code:

```
<?php echo '<meta name="description" content="Read more about '; ?><rn:page_title/><?php echo 'on our site!">'; ?>
```

The only caveat I will mention is that you need to use single quotes for your echo, not double, because otherwise it renders something like:

```
<meta name="description" content="Read more about PAGE TITLE" on our site!"/>
```

Clearly not desirable. Also, remember to escape any single quotes. So if your site is "Joe's Big Jamboree" then you would have:

```
<?php echo '<meta name="description" content="Read more about '; ?><rn:page_title/><?php echo '. Only at Joe\'s Big Jamboree!">'; ?>
```

And it would render:

```
<meta name="description" content="Read more about PAGE TITLE. Only at Joe's Big Jamboree!"/>
```